# Paypal Rest API keeps returning malformed json error

Tags: python, api, rest, paypal

I am trying to create payment using `paypal` Rest API, but I keep getting this error response:

```
{"name":"MALFORMED_REQUEST","message":"The request JSON is not well formed.","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#MALFORMED_REQUEST","debug_id":"262cbdc417df7"}
```

here with my code:

```
payment_url = 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment'
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": "Bearer %s" % access_token}
data = {
        "intent": "sale",
        "redirect_urls": {
            "return_url": "http://localhost:8080/index.html",
            "cancel_url": "http://localhost:8080/index.html"
        },
        "payer": {
            "payment_method": "paypal"
        },
        "transactions": [
            {
                "amount": {
                    "total": "7.47",
                    "currency": "USD"
                },
                "details": {
                    "subtotal": "7.41",
                    "tax": "0.03",
                    "shipping": "0.03"
                },
                "description": "This is the payment transaction description.",
                "item_list": {
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "quantity": "1",
                            "name": "item",
                            "price": "7.41",
                            "currency": "USD",
                            "sku": "item"
                        }]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
    print headers
    print data
    r = requests.post(payment_url, headers=headers, data=data)
    print 'payment res', r.text
```

And I only get the response like this:

```
{"name":"MALFORMED_REQUEST","message":"The request JSON is not well formed.","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#MALFORMED_REQUEST","debug_id":"262cbdc417df7"}
```

I have seen quite a few questions regarding this kind of error, but none of them have solution yet. :(
The json formated post data is obviously valid. Otherwise, requests post method would raise exceptions. And the response is returned from paypal server, but I can't find any information from the link it gave. I have checked Rest API documentation, and I think I made the request exactly as the samples. What did I miss?

Any kind advice or solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your *return_url* and *cancel_url* values need to have quotes around them.  As the message says, your JSON is malformed.

Try this - http://jsonlint.com/ to see your errors.

Comment: Hi, Gandalf, thanks for your answer. The values return_url and cancel_url were string variables, and do have quotes.  The json is valid, otherwise the post requests will fail for the parameters. I think the problem is, the post requests to paypal api is done, but with a strange response i don't have a clue.